# IllegalStateException when calling blockingConnect in wear Service

Tags: android, assets, wear-os, illegalstateexception

I am trying to develop an Android wear app and pass an asset from the mobile helper activity. I have followed the official document for passing assets - [Transferring Assets](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html), but I am getting the following error when trying to load a bitmap from the asset passed in the `onDataChanged` function. Note that the code works when passing `String` values. The code is as follows:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromAsset(Bitmap bitmap, Asset asset) {
    if (asset == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset must be non-null");
    }

    ConnectionResult result = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
        return null;
    }

    InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(mGoogleApiClient, asset).await().getInputStream();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    if (assetInputStream == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInputStream);
    return bitmap;
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread
>   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.blockingConnect(Unknown Source)
>   ...

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was finally to execute the loadBitmapFromAsset in a runnable. Don't see why I didn't figure this out earlier... I have not found a similar post so hopefully it will help someone.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    ...
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means exactly what it says: you can't call `GoogleApiClient.blockingConnect` on the UI thread of your application. You need to set a callback before you connect to `GoogleApiClient`, and then do your processing in the `onConnected` callback.

There's a fine example of this at http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html. The part you're missing is within the `addConnectionCallbacks` call.

Comment: Thanks but that is what I am doing. The watch face service implements the following functions, DataApi.DataListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener. The problem happens when the onDataChanged function is called (after changing some settings on the mobile companion app) and I try to load bitmap from the asset passed. The function I am using is the same function (loadBitmapFromAsset) from the related documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this in Activity for creating asynctask

```
class doAsync(val handler: () -> Unit) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    init {
        execute()
    }
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
        handler()
        return null
    }
}
```

Now call this in onResume or onCreate

```
 doAsync{
        mGoogleApiClient?.blockingConnect()
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(object : ResultCallback<Status> {
            override fun onResult(status: Status) {
                mAuth?.signOut()

            }

        })
 }
```